# conversion from mp3 to ogg using php

Tags: php, ffmpeg, exec, mp4, ogg

I want to convert mp3 file to ogg. I tried the following code

```
exec("/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -vcodec libtheora -acodec libvorbis testjohn4545454.ogg",$output);
var_dump($output);
```

But it does not convert the file and it only returns `array(0) { }`
and it only takes a little execution time.

But the conversion is success when using ssh command.

Please give me solution.

Comment: Hard to give an immediate solution, did you give PHP a decent execution time for that to conclude with success? set_time_limit variable.

Comment: @Heapy It takes only a little execution time.

Comment: Web server user might not have enough permissions, did you check those?

Comment: @Heapy Yes i put 777 to all the files but it remains same.

Comment: @Heapy But it works when using SSH command

Comment: might want to also give absolute urls a try, just in case it's trying to load the file from another directory

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Thank you for the replies. I used `passthru()` instead of `exec()` and it works fine.

Comment: Might want to check out my answer outputting a log file, running it *in the background*, and also a progress bar. I've created the exact same thing as you pretty much. Don't need to upvote, I hope you find it useful.

Answer (score 3):

Funny thing here, you want to execute this in it's own process and **in the background**, otherwise your PHP script will hang whilst waiting for the conversion to complete.

The code:

`passthru("nohup /usr/local/bin/ffmpeg -i 1.mp4 -vcodec libtheora -acodec libvorbistestjohn4545454.ogg 1> /path/to/logfile.txt 2>&1 &");`

Note the "nohup" and the ampersand on the end: these should give you what you require. Also, you can now check your logfile periodically to make sure that it's doing what you want.

And finally, check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441517/ffmpeg-progress-bar-encoding-percentage-in-php) for creating a progress bar, if you like.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem once but i've choose to save and read files (input file and output converted file) in a apache writable folder
You can also check if convertion is alredy done via reading that directory.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check your disabled_functions configuration on PHP and see if exec is not there? Also you might want to enable all [error reporting](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) and after try to exec() with a simple bash echo and see how it goes. If all goes well then check if you are using the correct files, as Jamie pointed out, the working directory might be the wrong one so use absolute paths or relative, whatever is most convenient. The Unix command for checking what is the current working directory is `pwd`.

**Edit:** Also, [exec](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) has another caveat `When safe mode is enabled, you can only execute files within the safe_mode_exec_dir` so be sure to have a good read on the [manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) for other problems.