# Redirect a page from one page to another page without changing the url using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, joomla2.5

Is there any way to Redirect a page from one page to another page without changing the url using htaccess in joomla?

I want to change the url

http://idaycom.com/index.php/component/quates/

to

http://idaycom.com/index.php/component/quotes/

How to change it ?

here is my htaccess file

```
##
# @version      $Id: htaccess.txt 21101 2011-04-07 15:47:33Z dextercowley $
# @package      Joomla
# @copyright    Copyright (C) 2005 - 2011 Open Source Matters. All rights reserved.
# @license      GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
##

##
# READ THIS COMPLETELY IF YOU CHOOSE TO USE THIS FILE!
#
# The line just below this section: 'Options +FollowSymLinks' may cause problems
# with some server configurations.  It is required for use of mod_rewrite, but may already
# be set by your server administrator in a way that dissallows changing it in
# your .htaccess file.  If using it causes your server to error out, comment it out (add # to
# beginning of line), reload your site in your browser and test your sef url's.  If they work,
# it has been set by your server administrator and you do not need it set here.
##

## Can be commented out if causes errors, see notes above.
Options +FollowSymLinks

## Mod_rewrite in use.

RewriteEngine On

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/index\.php/component/quates   [NC]
RewriteRule .*   index.php/component/quotes   [R=301,L]

## Begin - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.
# If you experience problems on your site block out the operations listed below
# This attempts to block the most common type of exploit `attempts` to Joomla!
#
# Block out any script trying to base64_encode data within the URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} base64_encode[^(]*\([^)]*\) [OR]
# Block out any script that includes a <script> tag in URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (<|%3C)([^s]*s)+cript.*(>|%3E) [NC,OR]
# Block out any script trying to set a PHP GLOBALS variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
# Block out any script trying to modify a _REQUEST variable via URL.
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
# Return 403 Forbidden header and show the content of the root homepage
RewriteRule .* index.php [F]
#
## End - Rewrite rules to block out some common exploits.

## Begin - Custom redirects
#
# If you need to redirect some pages, or set a canonical non-www to
# www redirect (or vice versa), place that code here. Ensure those
# redirects use the correct RewriteRule syntax and the [R=301,L] flags.
#
## End - Custom redirects

##
# Uncomment following line if your webserver's URL
# is not directly related to physical file paths.
# Update Your Joomla! Directory (just / for root).
##

# RewriteBase /

## Begin - Joomla! core SEF Section.
#
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
#
# If the requested path and file is not /index.php and the request
# has not already been internally rewritten to the index.php script
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
# and the request is for something within the component folder,
# or for the site root, or for an extensionless URL, or the
# requested URL ends with one of the listed extensions
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} /component/|(/[^.]*|\.(php|html?|feed|pdf|vcf|raw))$ [NC]
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
# and the requested path and file doesn't directly match a physical folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# internally rewrite the request to the index.php script
RewriteRule .* index.php [L]
#
## End - Joomla! core SEF Section.
```

Comment: Give an example. Can't understand how could be possible to redirect to another page with the same URL, unless you are talking about the same URL-path in another domain.

Comment: @faa I am working in jooomla 2.5 site.I want to change the url
http://idaycom.com/index.php/component/quates/
to
http://idaycom.com/index.php/component/quotes/

Comment: Okay. It is indeed a different URL. Which strings are fixed and which are dynamic?

Comment: @faa  idaycom.com/index.php/component/ is fixed.only want to change quates to quotes

Comment: @faa Is that possible by htaccess ?

Comment: @faa how we can re write a url to another one in joomla by htaccess

Comment: Now it is tested and working.

Comment: @faa i put this code in the htaccess.But it remains the same.

Comment: @faa When i take this page idaycom.com/index.php/component/quates .It shows the same url.

Comment: Hey @Preethy, could you please go back and 'tick' an answer you found useful / your own answer? :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14957544/conversion-from-mp3-to-ogg-using-php/14958338#14958338

Answer (score 3):

You can try this one buddy:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^yoursite.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.yoursite.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I used this on my website.

Answer (score 2):

You may try this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  ^/index\.php/component/quates   [NC]
RewriteRule .*   index.php/component/quotes   [R=301,L]
```

Redirects permanently

`http://idaycom.com/index.php/component/quates`

To

`http://idaycom.com/index.php/component/quotes`

For silent mapping, replace [R=301,L] with [L]

Comment: Please copy-paste the whole rule-set in my answer to the .htaccess file in root directory. It redirects as described. Make sure the browser's cache is cleared. If it fails, maybe there are other rules?

Comment: Please see the whole rules in my htacces file

Comment: Can you please give me your email address.so that it will easy to communicate

Comment: First try to copy-paste it in your question changing all sensitive content, so everybody can see it and eventually answer the question too.

Comment: @Preethy I am not familiar with Joomla and can't see the reason why it doesn't redirect to `/quotes`, but shouldn't this rule-set be placed after the comment `## Begin - Custom redirects` in your .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

you can try with many ways:

```
RedirectMatch "^/existingfile\.html/?$" "http://example.com/newfile.php"
```

this will redirect your existing url to new url