# catch percentage File conversion ffmpeg

Tags: php, mysql, ffmpeg

I've been thinking about implementing a new function on my system.
so I thought to show the state of the file conversion.
I thought of a logic to it.
updating table from the database according to the percentage of file conversion.

```
<?
exec('ffmpeg -i p17prdvj251lk11d3v12ntijfq2u1.mp4 -vf scale=-1:360 -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast output.flv');
for($i = 0; $i <= 1; $i++){
    mysql_query("UPDATE progress SET pss='".$i."' WHERE id='1'");
}
```

the problem is that I do not know if it's possible to get the percentage.
I thought about using the extension of ffmpeg and create a function to convert the files but do not know if it will work

Comment: could you 'fake' it based on file-size and processing time?

Comment: I actually wanted more precision in processing time

Comment: could not resist: http://xkcd.com/612/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11441517/ffmpeg-progress-bar-encoding-percentage-in-php?rq=1